# Visual Studio extension not coming in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility

I have created a simple visual studio extension through VS2015.
Build the project and start debugging. The experimental instance of Visual Studio appears.

In the experimental window, I can see the extension in the tool menu. but I can't see that in solution explorer or by right click on any .cs file.

I have installed one extension online "style cop", that I can see both at tools and by right click on any .cs file.and I actually wanted to run that extension by right click of a .cs file

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please post how you've registered the tool window in your package?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something?

If you want to add command menu on tool menu and context menu in your solution explorer, you need to add new command menu for solution explorer, please right click project -> add -> new item -> extensibility -> custom command -> add.

Then modify your vsct file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!--  This is the file that defines the actual layout and type of the commands.
        It is divided in different sections (e.g. command definition, command
        placement, ...), with each defining a specific set of properties.
        See the comment before each section for more details about how to
        use it. -->

  <!--  The VSCT compiler (the tool that translates this file into the binary
        format that VisualStudio will consume) has the ability to run a preprocessor
        on the vsct file; this preprocessor is (usually) the C++ preprocessor, so
        it is possible to define includes and macros with the same syntax used
        in C++ files. Using this ability of the compiler here, we include some files
        defining some of the constants that we will use inside the file. -->

  <!--This is the file that defines the IDs for all the commands exposed by VisualStudio. -->
  <Extern href="stdidcmd.h" />

  <!--This header contains the command ids for the menus provided by the shell. -->
  <Extern href="vsshlids.h" />

  <!--The Commands section is where commands, menus, and menu groups are defined.
      This section uses a Guid to identify the package that provides the command defined inside it. -->
  <Commands package="guidFirstCommandPackage">
    <!-- Inside this section we have different sub-sections: one for the menus, another
    for the menu groups, one for the buttons (the actual commands), one for the combos
    and the last one for the bitmaps used. Each element is identified by a command id that
    is a unique pair of guid and numeric identifier; the guid part of the identifier is usually
    called "command set" and is used to group different command inside a logically related
    group; your package should define its own command set in order to avoid collisions
    with command ids defined by other packages. -->

    <!-- In this section you can define new menu groups. A menu group is a container for
         other menus or buttons (commands); from a visual point of view you can see the
         group as the part of a menu contained between two lines. The parent of a group
         must be a menu. -->
    <Groups>
      <Group guid="guidFirstCommandPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS" />
      </Group>

      **<Group guid="guidFirstCommandPackageCmdSet" id="ContextMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE" />
      </Group>**
    </Groups>

    <!--Buttons section. -->
    <!--This section defines the elements the user can interact with, like a menu command or a button
        or combo box in a toolbar. -->
    <Buttons>
      <!--To define a menu group you have to specify its ID, the parent menu and its display priority.
          The command is visible and enabled by default. If you need to change the visibility, status, etc, you can use
          the CommandFlag node.
          You can add more than one CommandFlag node e.g.:
              <CommandFlag>DefaultInvisible</CommandFlag>
              <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
          If you do not want an image next to your command, remove the Icon node /> -->
      <Button guid="guidFirstCommandPackageCmdSet" id="FirstCommandId" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidFirstCommandPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Open NotePad</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      **<Button guid="guidFirstCommandPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidItemContextCommand" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidFirstCommandPackageCmdSet" id="ContextMenuGroup" />**
        <Icon guid="guidImages1" id="bmpPic1" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Invoke ItemContextCommand</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
    </Buttons>

    <!--The bitmaps section is used to define the bitmaps that are used for the commands.-->
    <Bitmaps>
      <!--  The bitmap id is defined in a way that is a little bit different from the others:
            the declaration starts with a guid for the bitmap strip, then there is the resource id of the
            bitmap strip containing the bitmaps and then there are the numeric ids of the elements used
            inside a button definition. An important aspect of this declaration is that the element id
            must be the actual index (1-based) of the bitmap inside the bitmap strip. -->
      <Bitmap guid="guidImages" href="Resources\FirstCommand.png" usedList="bmpPic1, bmpPic2, bmpPicSearch, bmpPicX, bmpPicArrows, bmpPicStrikethrough" />
      <Bitmap guid="guidImages1" href="Resources\ItemContextCommand.png" usedList="bmpPic1, bmpPic2, bmpPicSearch, bmpPicX, bmpPicArrows, bmpPicStrikethrough" />
    </Bitmaps>
  </Commands>

  <KeyBindings>  
    <KeyBinding guid="guidFirstCommandPackageCmdSet" id="FirstCommandId" key1="VK_LEFT" mod1="ALT" editor="guidVSStd97" />  
  </KeyBindings>

  <Symbols>
    <!-- This is the package guid. -->
    <GuidSymbol name="guidFirstCommandPackage" value="{e8cc719c-6c8e-4667-8273-eab9816fe63b}" />

    <!-- This is the guid used to group the menu commands together -->
    <GuidSymbol name="guidFirstCommandPackageCmdSet" value="{4d5e3834-3416-4a31-a351-4d2d1b07537f}">
      <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroup" value="0x1020" />
      **<IDSymbol name="ContextMenuGroup" value="0x1030" />**
      <IDSymbol name="FirstCommandId" value="0x0100" />
      <IDSymbol value="4129" name="cmdidItemContextCommand" />
    </GuidSymbol>

    <GuidSymbol name="guidImages" value="{ec51c1a5-39aa-416a-b662-96258c595f06}">
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic2" value="2" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicSearch" value="3" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicX" value="4" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicArrows" value="5" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicStrikethrough" value="6" />
    </GuidSymbol>

    <GuidSymbol value="{04d7532f-01d2-4048-9150-90ac99b6fede}" name="guidImages1">
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic2" value="2" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicSearch" value="3" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicX" value="4" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicArrows" value="5" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicStrikethrough" value="6" />
    </GuidSymbol>
  </Symbols>
</CommandTable>
```

If you want to custom command only for cs file. please add a custom event on your command. like this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="ItemContextCommand.cs" company="Company">
//     Copyright (c) Company.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using EnvDTE80;
using EnvDTE;

namespace FirstMenuCommand
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Command handler
    /// </summary>
    internal sealed class ItemContextCommand
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Command ID.
        /// </summary>
        public const int CommandId = 4129;

        /// <summary>
        /// Command menu group (command set GUID).
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly Guid CommandSet = new Guid("4d5e3834-3416-4a31-a351-4d2d1b07537f");

        /// <summary>
        /// VS Package that provides this command, not null.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly Package package;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ItemContextCommand"/> class.
        /// Adds our command handlers for menu (commands must exist in the command table file)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="package">Owner package, not null.</param>
        private ItemContextCommand(Package package)
        {
            if (package == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("package");
            }

            this.package = package;

            OleMenuCommandService commandService = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
            if (commandService != null)
            {
                var menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
                //var menuItem = new MenuCommand(this.MenuItemCallback, menuCommandID);

                OleMenuCommand oleMenuItem = new OleMenuCommand(new EventHandler(MenuItemCallback), menuCommandID);
                oleMenuItem.BeforeQueryStatus += new EventHandler(OnBeforeQueryStatus);
                commandService.AddCommand(oleMenuItem);

                //commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the instance of the command.
        /// </summary>
        public static ItemContextCommand Instance
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the service provider from the owner package.
        /// </summary>
        private IServiceProvider ServiceProvider
        {
            get
            {
                return this.package;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton instance of the command.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="package">Owner package, not null.</param>
        public static void Initialize(Package package)
        {
            Instance = new ItemContextCommand(package);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function is the callback used to execute the command when the menu item is clicked.
        /// See the constructor to see how the menu item is associated with this function using
        /// OleMenuCommandService service and MenuCommand class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Event sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event args.</param>
        private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string message = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Inside {0}.MenuItemCallback()", this.GetType().FullName);
            string title = "ItemContextCommand";

            // Show a message box to prove we were here
            VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(
                this.ServiceProvider,
                message,
                title,
                OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
                OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
                OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
        }

        void OnBeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DTE2 dte2 = (DTE2)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
            var myCommand = sender as OleMenuCommand;

            object[] selectedItems = (object[])dte2.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer.SelectedItems;
            foreach (EnvDTE.UIHierarchyItem selectedUIHierarchyItem in selectedItems)
            {
                if (selectedUIHierarchyItem.Object is EnvDTE.ProjectItem)
                {
                    EnvDTE.ProjectItem item = selectedUIHierarchyItem.Object as EnvDTE.ProjectItem;
                    if (item.Name.EndsWith(".cs"))
                    {
                        myCommand.Enabled = true;
                        myCommand.Visible = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myCommand.Enabled = false;
                        myCommand.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the id in the .vsct file.

```
<Group guid="guidChangesetViewerCommandPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_TOOL_PROJWIN"/>
  </Group>
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-toolbars?view=vs-2017) is the list of guids and ids of different windows of visual studio.